# Multi-line text retrieved from file via \input, within a newcommand declaration, passing newly declared command as argument of standard letter class

Tags: macros, errors, letters

I have put together a minimum working example consisting of a number of files

```
mwe.tex     % instance of personal letter
address.tex % full address of individual being addressed in mwe.tex
C:\LocalTeX\tex\latex\my\mygeneralmatter.sty    % author's address and signature defined here
C:\LocalTeX\tex\latex\my\myletter.cls   % author's address and signature defined here
```

Here are the file contents:

### mwe.tex

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{myletter}

\newcommand{\thetoaddress}{\input{address}} % doesn't compile
%\newcommand{\thetoaddress}{%
%Addressee name\\
%Addressee title\\
%Address line 1\\
%Address line 2\\
%Address line 3%
%}  % does compile
\newcommand{\theopening}{Dear addressee,}
\newcommand{\theclosing}{Sincerely,}
\newcommand{\thepostscript}{}

\begin{document}
I would like to thank you for your recommendation during the hiring process for the position of position with company.

I have thoroughly enjoyed being a part of company.  It has indeed been a privelege to have worked with such a competant team.  

I very much appreciate the support.
\end{document}
```

### address.tex

```
Person\\
Title\\
Address line 1\\
Address line 2\\
Address line 3
```

### mygeneralmatter.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mygeneralmatter}[2013/05/21 a package containing general matter]

\newcommand{\email}{first.last@domain.com}  % appropriate email address

\newcommand{\phone}{(999) 999 9999}     % phone number

% company name and address
\newcommand{\authoraddress}{%
Address line 1 \\%
Address line 2  \\%
Address line 3 %
}%

% company name, address and phone numbers
\newcommand{\authoraddresslong}{%
\authoraddress \\%
\phone \\%
\email
}%

% signature for formal letters
\newcommand{\authorsignature}{First Last}
```

### myletter.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myletter}[2013/04/22 a class for a personal letter which essentially preloads the authors current personal information]
\LoadClass[]{letter}

\RequirePackage{mygeneralmatter}    % provides the commands: \authorsignature, \authoraddresslong

\signature{\authorsignature}    % signature of the letter defined in jclgenmatter.sty
\address{\authoraddresslong}    % author's long address defined in jclgenmatter.sty

\AtBeginDocument{%
\begin{letter}{\thetoaddress}
\opening{\theopening}
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\closing{\theclosing}
\ps{\thepostscript}
\end{letter}
}
```

Note that the file `address.tex` is alongside `mwe.tex` (same path).  Note also that I have updated my local TeX system to be aware of the files `mygeneralmatter.sty` and `myletter.cls` by doing MikTeX --> Maintenance --> Settings --> Refresh FNDB

This is the error that I receive when compiling `mwe.tex`

```
! Argument of \@no@pgbk has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.22 \end{document}
```

Specifically, the problem is summarized as the newcommand `\thetoaddress` is being defined in `mwe.tex` as multi-line text which is retrieved from a file `address.tex` via the `\input{}` command.  The newly declared command `\thetwoaddress` is then passed as an argument to the standard letter environment in the file `myletter.cls`

More generally, the problem may be summarized as multi-line text retrieved from file via `\input`, within a newcommand declaration and then passing newly declared command as argument of standard letter class

Can anyone suggest an approach which would allow me to refer to a `to address' stored in a file from the instance of the personalized letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add the following lines to your class files:

```
\RequirePackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getaddressfrom}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thetoaddress}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\defineaddress}[1]{\def\thetoaddress{#1}}
```

and change the part where you start the letter with

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\def\tempa{\endgroup\begin{letter}}
    \expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\thetoaddress}%
  \opening{\theopening}
}
```

In this way the `\begin{letter}` command will be presented with the expanded form of `\thetoaddress`. This is important because the `letter` class considers specially the part of this argument up to the first `\\`.

In order to read an address from a file, say

```
\documentclass{myletter}

\getaddressfrom{address}

\newcommand{\theopening}{Dear addressee,}
\newcommand{\theclosing}{Sincerely,}
\newcommand{\thepostscript}{}

\begin{document}
I would like to thank you for your recommendation during the hiring
process for the position of position with company.

I have thoroughly enjoyed being a part of company.  It has indeed 
been a privelege to have worked with such a competant team.  

I very much appreciate the support.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, instead of `\getaddressfrom` you can specify directly an address with

```
\defineaddress{John Doe\\
  42, Some Street\\
  12345 Somecity}
```

Comment: I modified my example code trying both of the suggestions made above.  Each solution resulted in successful compilation.  Thanks very much for the suggestions and thanks for pointing me to the catchfile package.

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand{\thetoaddress}{\protect\input{address}} % does compile
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same problem, I decided to increase variables and 8 to 9 and 6.5 to 7 in

```
\textheight=9in % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\textwidth=7in  % text width of `6.5in` leaves 1 inch for right margin
```

I hope it useful.

Comment: This does not answer the question.